# Compute a multiple integral$\iint_{[0,1]^2} (xy)^{xy} dxdy$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

$$\text{Compute} :\iint_{[0,1]^2} (xy)^{xy} dxdy$$

I am thinking about changing the variable, $x=u,y={v \over u}$.But it doesn't work.

I just found that the answer is$\int_0^1 t^t dt$.Maybe my idea is right?

Comment: Just to be clear, is this $(xy)^{xy}$ or $x\, y^{xy}$?

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip My bad,i'll correct it.

Comment: In response to your edit, if you set $t= xy$ and $s=y$, the Jacobian determinant is $\partial(s,t)/\partial(x,y)=y$, implying $\partial(x,y)/\partial(s,t)=1/y=1/s$. So you get $\int_0^1\int_0^s t^t (1/s)\,dt\,ds,$ but I don't see how to get to $\int_0^1 t^t\,dt$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building on Grumpy's comment, changing the order of integration in $\int_0^1 \int_0^s t^t (1/s) \ dt\  ds$ gives
$$\int_0^1 \int_t^1 t^t (1/s)\ ds\ dt = \int_0^1 t^t (-\ln t)\ dt.$$

The claim in the question thus amounts to showing that $\int_0^1 t^t (1+\ln t)\ dt = 0$, which follows readily from the substitution $u = t \ln t$.

Comment: It is interesting to note that in this case you can switch the order of integration because $t^t 1/s$ is non-negative ; this is Fubini's theorem. +1

Comment: Nice. I got that expression, didn't see what to do, and posted it as a comment.

Comment: Nice!Thanks a lot!

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva  I'm sorry that I can't figure out why $\int_0^1 t^t (1+\ln t)\ dt = 0$ by the substitution $u = t \ln t$.Could you possibly explain it in a little more detail?

Comment: @GEE20151011 : Next time ask the answerer of the question for that haha :) 

$e^u = e^{t \ln t} = (e^{\ln t})^t = t^t$ and $du = (\ln t + 1) dt$. So you get the integral $\int_{u(0)}^{u(1)} e^u du = 0$ (because $u(0) = \lim_{t \to 0^+} t \ln t = 0$ and $u(1) = 1 \ln 1 = 0$).

Comment: This explains why you need to take a limit : http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot[t^t%281%2BLog[t]%29%2C+{t%2C0%2C1}] (okay for some reason the link is not entirely "put in blue"... copy paste it in your URL bar.)

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva Thank you sooo much! :)

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva I thought the answerer is you,and I checked the answer again and just found that the answerer is Erick Wong. Anyway,thank you so much.:p